# ¿Qué hacer ante ediciones en respuestas de otros que añaden información?

Tags: discusión, respuesta, ediciones-sugeridas

Creo que no se ha tratado el tema anteriormente o no lo he encontrado.
Surgió en el chat una [conversación](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40115188#40115188) sobre si se debería aprobar o rechazar una edición sobre una respuesta que añadía información.

Vamos a suponer que el añadido aporta información útil y correcta (en otro caso está claro que se debería rechazar). Quizá lo más correcto sea poner un mensaje al autor de la respuesta para que añada nuestra aportación si le parece bien o preguntar si podemos editar si en el comentario no se puede poner por ser código o mucho texto.

El caso es que en la cola de revisión nos encontramos con ediciones que debemos aceptar o rechazar y me surge la duda de qué hacer cuando alguien a añadido algo que puede ser una buena aportación a la respuesta pero no parezca una respuesta completa por si sola. ¿Cómo soléis actuar en estos casos si habeis tenido que hacerlo, o si no, cómo creéis que se debe actuar?

Comment: Creo que eso debería decidir el autor de la respuesta si lo ve oportuno o no... lo demás sería contra la decisión del autor

Answer (score 4):

Yo creo que depende.

He tenido notificaciones de este tipo en respuestas que tengo en el sitio en inglés. Lo que ha sucedido en esos casos es que los mismos usuarios **han rechazado la edición** y sugirieron publicar una nueva respuesta. Cabe resaltar que esto ha sucedido porque mi respuesta **no era del estilo wiki de comunidad**.

Si tienes ejemplos, casos para agregar y demás, pienso que deberías publicar una nueva respuesta. Lo que suelo hacer en estos casos es indicar que mi respuesta es para **complementar** otra de las respuestas, usualmente colocando un link a la respuesta que quiero complementar. De esta forma, respeto las ideas iniciales del autor de la respuesta y no mezclo sus ideas con las mías. De acuerdo, no será quizás la respuesta aceptada por el OP, pero la motivación del sitio es **ayudar**. A la par de ayudar con el contenido del sitio, también debemos **respetar la decisión del usuario** en el contenido de la respuesta que brinda. Lo que sí se puede es **comentar la respuesta** para decirle al usuario cómo puede mejorar aún más su respuesta.

En el caso de respuestas estilo wiki de comunidad, la edición es totalmente libre. Si la edición suma, considero que debería aceptarse.