# ¿Debo modificar las respuestas de otros usuarios?

Tags: discusión, ediciones, convenciones-sociales

Apenas recibí un comentario que decía a la letra:

> El dueño de la respuesta es otro usuario , y el solo puede modificar dicha respuesta

Yo entiendo que el privilegio de editar preguntas y respuestas incluye respuestas de otros usuarios.

En mi caso lo hice porque la mejora que le pidieron de su respuesta la puso en los comentarios y petendí ahorrale tiempo a alguien que lo buscara agregando su comentaio al final de la respuesta.

¿Es un caso válido?
¿Hay otros casos válidos en que sea correcto modificar una respuesta de otra persona?

Comment: Esta [pregunta se relaciona bastante](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2261/es-correcto-editar-una-pregunta-cerrada-de-otro-usuario-para-mejorarla)

Comment: De [¿Cuándo debería editar publicaciones?](/help/privileges/edit): _Siempre que veas que puedes mejorar una publicación y te apetezca. ¡Fomentamos la edición!_. Si es el caso que mencionas, creo que es más que bienvenido.

Answer (score -1):

Yo te doy mi opinión. Las ediciones deberían limitarse a criterios de formato o de redacción, y no deberían afectar mas que en casos puntuales a su contenido.

Esto es especialmente importante en las respuestas. En varias ocasiones he votado en contra de una edición de una respuesta que pretendía arreglar el código de la respuesta. Si permitimos eso, podríamos encontrarnos con una guerra de ediciones para mejorar un código. Yo considero que no es bueno permitirlo. Si tienes un código que mejorar, propónlo en tu propia respuesta.

En el caso que nos expones, yo te digo lo que habría hecho (no se exactamente lo que hiciste ya que no nos dices en que pregunta era. Yo habría añadido un comentario al creador de la respuesta explicándole que era mejor que editara el mismo su respuesta para añadir la mejora que había puesto en los comentarios. Si tras un tiempo prudencial el op no lo hiciera, me plantearía editar su respuesta.

Resumiendo, creo que hay que ser muy respetuosos con lo que otra persona ha escrito, por eso las ediciones de contenido deben reducirse a lo mínimo imprescindible.

Edit:

Aclaro que mi respuesta se refiere principalmente a la pregunta de OP *¿Hay otros casos válidos en que sea correcto modificar una respuesta de otra persona?*

En cuanto al ejemplo que él pone, siempre y cuando sea añadir algo que el que respondió ha añadido en un comentario, no me parece incorrecto, aunque personalmente como he dicho yo primero le pediría al autor que incorporase el comentario a su respuesta él mismo.

Preguntas anteriores relacionadas:

[¿Qué hacer ante ediciones en respuestas de otros que añaden información?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2806/15301)

[¿Que hacer con las preguntas formuladas en inglés o en otro idioma?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362/que-hacer-con-las-preguntas-formuladas-en-ingl%C3%A9s-o-en-otro-idioma)

Comment: Una vez escribes una publicación en esta red, accedes a que su contenido sea de tipo [CC-BY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). Esto permite que sea adaptado, transformado y lo que se quiera. Obviamente que el contenido "es" de quien lo escribió, pero no posee un candado por el que nada puede cambiarse. Y precisamente ahí radica la potencia de la red, en que todas las publicaciones son potencialmente wiki.

Comment: Me parece que pikoh habla mas de un tema de etiqueta. Puede que en este caso quien vio la edicion no haya visto que estaba agregando informacion a la respuesta que esta en un comentario (en la venta de aprobar ediciones eso no figura). En ese caso habria que aclarar bien el porque se esta haciendo la edicion.

Comment: @fedorqui lamento no estar de acuerdo contigo. Precisamente hay una diferencia entre una respuesta y un wiki de comunidad. En wiki el "dueño" de la respuesta da su permiso para que cualquiera pueda modificarla, corregirla o **ampliarla**. Por supuesto que se puede cambiar tanto preguntas como respuestas, mi punto es que para modificar el contenido añadiendo o cambiando el código fuente expuesto por ejemplo, hay que ser muy muy respetuoso.

Comment: @fedorqui por cierto..una de las razones de rechazo de ediciones es "Claramente en conflicto con el autor", que es básicamente lo que yo defiendo

Comment: @Pikoh la línea entre wiki y no wiki es fina. [Grandes respuestas](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16957078/revisions) pueden tener muchísimas ediciones sin perder el "sello" del autor (de hecho antes la conversión era automática tras 10 ediciones). Creo que es bueno añadir a la respuesta todo lo que sea mejorar el contenido para el que venga después. En este caso particular, creo que coincidimos en que es bueno añadir un texto que solo aparecía en comentarios, para así darle mejor visibilidad. Si resulta que al autor le incomoda, pues habrá que ver por qué.

Comment: @fedorqui por supuesto. En el caso que se está planteando no tengo ninguna crítica que hacer. Yo mas bien me refería a la segunda parte de la pregunta _¿Hay otros casos válidos en que sea correcto modificar una respuesta de otra persona?_

Comment: Sí, este caso particular parece bastante claro pues era un usuario relativamente nuevo que [explicó al OP en comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/135014/filtrar-array-de-objetos-en-javascript/135019#comment252265_135019). El caso general es complicado. Yo suelo añadir la info si estoy seguro de que es correcta; si el autor se "pica" a veces he añadido otra respuesta

Comment: @fedorqui este ultimo caso es en el que no estoy de acuerdo. Yo prefiero que se añada otra respuesta o comentar al que respondió la posible modificación. Por cierto,todo es subjetivo, pero en la ayuda que enlazas [¿Cuándo debería editar publicaciones?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) especifica _para clarificar el sentido de una publicación sin cambiarla_

Comment: @fedorqui me refiero a esto por ejemplo https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356020/579895

Comment: @Pikoh el que comentas es un caso interesante. Como dices, todo es subjetivo, por ejemplo una edición así a mí no me importaría que la hicieran en una respuesta mía, si considerara que la mejora. Eso sí, si la viera en la cola de sugerencias de edición sería muy cauto a la hora de aceptarla.

Comment: @fedorqui claro, yo en esos casos (no consigo encontralo, pero aqui en meta hubo una pregunta sobre el tema) prefiero que sea el propio autor el que acepte la edición (hablando de usuarios sin permisos de edición). Yo, personalmente, preferiría comentarlo con el autor antes de modificar su respuesta :)